# How to use pronominal adverbs

Tags: grammar, pronoun, adverb

How does one determine what da-compound to use if there is no fixed preposition in a sentence? For example: Sie konnte ihre Brille nicht finden, denn sie saß *darauf*.  How can I know what pronominal adverb to use?

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Your question is unclear and thus may be closed. Please [edit] it to include further information/context. I find it hard to imagine such a case. All you need to know about editing, closing and reopening questions can be found in the [help].

Comment: An example would go a long way already.

Comment: Your example: ***auf** etwas sitzen*.

Comment: @Jan What if in a sentence, you have to fill in the missing pronominal adverb? Like during an exam.

Comment: Quite simply, you choose the preposition that makes the most sense in the given context. This is not a grammar question.

Comment: You already use an pronominal adverb in your example. It is *darauf*. Doesn't this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's no fixed preposition in your sentence, because you don't know it. Some verbs tend to prefer to be in company of certain prepositions (which, again, highly depends on the context). By that I mean, that you even something need to learn the pairs

> ( `preposition` ,`verb` ).

Don't forget to learn the case the preposition has.